How to adjust indentation on built-in bibliography in Word?
Is there any way to adjust the paragraph settings for the automatic bibliography in Word? I can't seem to find this anywhere, and the help documentation does not mention this.
I have used Word's built-in reference manager to create citations and generate a bibliography for my paper. The Word-generated bibliography inserts with a left indentation value of 0.00.  I want this to be set to 0.06.  I can manually change the indentation by selecting the content of the bibliography and adjusting the paragraph settings.  However, anytime the citations and bibliography are updated (e.g. manually or when printing/saving) the indentation gets reset to 0.00.
I would prefer NOT to have to change the paragraph settings for all the styles used in this paper just to work around this bibliography.  Please help.

There are specific writing styles, Word follows those writing styles, what writing style are you following?

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but the behavior described (Word changes the indent back to 0.00) happens no matter what reference style I am using (APA, MLA, Chicago, IEEE, etc.).

Are you following APA or MLA style guidelines? The reason I ask is you can modify the guidelines within Word. However, if you are this for paper you intend to do turn in for an assignment for educational purposes you really should follow the guidelines without modifying the indentation.
